# how to represent mp3 file to binary number python

Tags: python, audio, mp3, binaryfiles, converters

I have a project where the user will enter a song and password. the password will be inserted into the song with spread spectrum steganography. This project is made using the django model, where the location of the data is stored in the database while the files that have been entered will be on the laptop's local storage.

At this stage, I want to insert a binary password (1 and 0) into the song. then i have to represent the song to binary numbers / representation (1 and 0)

for the example : I was upload `mymusic.mp3`, using Python, the file will be

> 110100101010

songs that have been uploaded will go into the media/mp3/thesongwasupload.mp3 and with django, I took the last location of the uploaded song to play the song with variable name last_song

**what I just want is to represent the uploaded song into binary numbers 0 and 1**

here's my code:

```
def homepage(request):
    form = AudioForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            last_audio = Audio_store.objects.all().last()
            print(last_audio)
            # readbinary(last_audio)
            plaintext = Audio_store.objects.all().values_list('password').last()
            key = Audio_store.objects.all().values_list('key').last()
            pt = plaintext[0]
            ky = key[0]
            ky16 = pelengkap(ky)
            context={'form':form, 'last_audio':last_audio}
            return render(request, "homepage.html", context)

    context={'form':form}
    return render(request, "homepage.html", context=context)

def readbinary(audio):
    b=BitArray(bytes=open(r'mp3/'+audio.name,'rb').read())

    # Store result
    with open('txt/'+audio.name, 'w') as file1: 
        file1.write(b.bin)
```

Comment: "binary", "decimal", "octal", "hexdecimal",... are not file formats ("binary", in another sense of the term that the one you are using, is sometimes used as opposite as "text" to designate the kind of formats that are not readable by a text editor). They are ways humans may read data. Your file is a bunch of bytes. Number between 0 and 255. And you can choose to show those bytes as a list of decimal numbers (between `0` and `255`) or as a list of hexadecimal numbers (between `0x00` and `0xff`) or binary numbers (between `00000000` and `11111111`). Or many other variants.

Comment: Those who say "files are already binary" (which is a very common, but not very true saying), are half-right. Most machine (in fact, absolutely all machines. But theoretically, nothing says so) stores data as a bunch of binary values (not 1 and 0. But something that codes 1 and 0. Like +5V and 0V. Or "transparent hole" vs "dark hole". Etc). But that is not really related to your problem (that is why they are also half-wrong). Your problem would be exactly the same with an alien machine, using ternary base (but still running python). So you don't really care that "files are already binary" or no

Comment: and how to represent bytes to binary numbers? @chrslg

Comment: But the point is, you can't "convert a file to binary". You can display its content with a program of yours in binary. Or play it with a mp3 player. Or dispaly it in octal. Etc. But not "convert" it.

Comment: i see, i was change "convert" to represent @chrslg

Comment: In python you can `with open("file.mp3", "rb") as f: s=f.read()` to get the bytes. And then `bin(s[0])` is the binary representation of the 1st byte. `bin(s[1])` of the second, etc.

Comment: Note that the `b` in `"rb"` means "binary". But that is the other meaning of the term "binary" I was referring to earlier. It means we don't assume that the content of the file is readable text. And so, `read` wont return string, but bytes.

Comment: Ok, saw your edit. So that is an entirely different story. And a huge "XY problem" indeed. When I mentionned XY problem sooner, I was referring to exactly that, and I had the feeling that in reality you had absolutely no interest at all in binary version of your file. Because, you think you want it, but I assure you, you don't. It is totally irrelevant for your project. There is to way you can hide a single bit among the bits of your mp3 file: if you change only one bit, then the mp3 is broken.

Comment: And further more, you have no reason to want a binary representation (a string of 0 and 1). And you are probably thinking "but you are the one who told be to say 'representation'". Yes: because that was what you were asking. But I am also the one who told you that data is data. You don't need "binary" data. You need the data, that's all. And then use reasonning on the bits, but not from a string of "0" and "1". But from tests, like "x%2" that tells your whether the last bit of x is 0 or 1. or "(x>>k)&1" that tells you if the kth bit (from the right) is 0 or 1.

Comment: So, you just need the data. But not the 1 and 0 from the mp3 file. Those are bytes of the mp3 compression format. You can't touch them. You need the data of the song. So you need a mp3 library to get the list of numbers representing a song in a mp3 file.

Comment: `pydub` is an example of such a library. Or `audiofile`. With one of those, you can read your mp3, get the sound samples as a list of numbers. Alter those numbers using bitwise operations. And then save back the file.

Answer (score 0):

This works uisng [bitstring](https://pypi.org/project/bitstring/)

```
import os
from bitstring import BitArray

b=BitArray(bytes=open(r"file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",'rb').read())

# Store result
with open('binary_mp3.txt', 'w') as file1: 
    file1.write(b.bin)
```

Sample output I got

[image: out]

Comment: how to open it if my data was file object?

Comment: you mean to write output to different file? instead of text file?

Comment: no, so i was get mp3 file using model and save it to last_audio. when i want to play the music, i get the last_audio. and how to using it to open the file using bitarray? i was give my code

Comment: I will try that...still trying to understand your requiremnet...At first in question you only mentioned you need to convert mp3 to binary ...but i dont understand this terms last audio, getting file from model....can u explain one more time pls

Comment: @HelpMeInDjango You've to explain what you are really trying to do. I mean, not "convert to binary" or anything like that. But why are your trying to do so. To achieve what? What project are you on. Apparently it is a backend. So, what does this web app do? The user send a ".mp3", and then what?  Because this looks a lot like a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: i was update it @chrslg

Comment: by the way, if i want to return the represent binary 1 0, how to do it?